# SQL Server Output Clause into a scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any "simple" way to do this or I need to pass by a table variable with the "OUTPUT ... INTO" syntax?

```
DECLARE @someInt int

INSERT INTO MyTable2(AIntColumn)
OUTPUT @SomeInt = Inserted.AIntColumn
VALUES(12)
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You need a table variable and it can be this simple.

```
declare @ID table (ID int)

insert into MyTable2(ID)
output inserted.ID into @ID
values (1)
```

Comment: But then I'd have to "SELECT @someInt = ID FROM @ID". I wanted to know if its possible to skip that extra step (and intermediary table variable) if all I need is the resulting int.

Comment: @Benoittr - That depends on how you are going to use the value, it might not be necessary, you could use the table in a from clause of a select statement. When you assign a variable you also need to be sure of that the insert only inserted one row. And if the insert only inserted one row, perhaps it is easier to get hold of what is used in the values clause directly instead of using `output`?

Comment: In the case of auto-generated value it is not always possible to know the values ahead of time(identity, computed columns). I understand there are many workaround. Still, you gave me the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Need it in a regular variable?  `DECLARE @InsertedIDResults TABLE (ID int); INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @InsertedIDResults VALUES('My Name', 30); DECLARE @InsertedID int = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @InsertedIDResults);`

Answer (score 45):

Over a year later... if what you need is get the auto generated id of a table, you can just

```
SELECT @ReportOptionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Otherwise, it seems like you are stuck with using a table.

Comment: The variable I was looking for really was something else then the identity column. Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Apparently this has issues in a Multi Processor Parallel Plan, and OUTPUT is the only always trustworthy method.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() might return something even if the *last* INSERT did not insert anything, right ? That would make it unusable in some cases.

Comment: @iDevlop that may be true (I don't really know) but I suppose you can workaround it using IF @@RowCount > 0... I'm really kind of thinking out loud though

Comment: It will not work for sequences. In this particular way, Mikael Eriksson answer is better.

Comment: better to use output clause

Comment: The bug @andrewb refers to is fixed in [2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019779/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identit).

Answer (score 13):

Way later but still worth mentioning is that you can also use variables to output values in the SET clause of an UPDATE or in the fields of a SELECT;

```
DECLARE @val1 int;
DECLARE @val2 int;
UPDATE [dbo].[PortalCounters_TEST]
SET @val1 = NextNum, @val2 = NextNum = NextNum + 1
WHERE [Condition] = 'unique value'
SELECT @val1, @val2
```

In the example above @val1 has the before value and @val2 has the after value although I suspect any changes from a trigger would not be in val2 so you'd have to go with the output table in that case. For anything but the simplest case, I think the output table will be more readable in your code as well.

One place this is very helpful is if you want to turn a column into a comma-separated list;

```
DECLARE @list varchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @comma varchar(2) = '';
SELECT @list = @list + @comma + County, @comma = ', ' FROM County
print @list
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the info I needed

Comment: WOW! I didn't know you can you do `SET @val2 = NextNum = NextNum + 1`.

Comment: Completely **different** to what was asked, didn't help at all, because I was looking for a way to assign an `OUTPUT` value to a variable in an `INSERT` clause using `INSERT-OUTPUT-VALUES` approach as asked by the asker.

Answer (score 10):

### Answer

You can use `@@IDENTITY` to get the last inserted id.

```
DECLARE @someInt int
INSERT INTO MyTable2(AIntColumn)
VALUES(12)
SET @someInt = @@IDENTITY;
```

Assuming your table has a primary key which you are looking to set as said variable.

#### Example schema

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable2(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [aIntColumn] [INT]
)
CREATE TABLE MyTable3(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [newInt] [INT],
    [FK_int] [INT]
)
```

Then you can use that in the next part of your script, e.g.

```
DECLARE @someInt INT;
INSERT INTO MyTable2(AIntColumn)
VALUES(12)
SET @someInt = @@IDENTITY;

--do something else
DECLARE @someInt2 INT;
INSERT INTO MyTable3(newInt, FK_int)
VALUES(101, @someInt)
SET @someInt2 = @@IDENTITY;

SELECT @someInt AS 'First Inserted ID ',  @someInt2 AS 'Second inserted ID';
```

Comment: this was the simplest and best answer for me.

Comment: Unfortunately @@IDENTITY is not to be trusted. You will sometimes get the last inserted id from a different table. It is extremely difficult to diagnose an error like this in production. Use OUTPUT clause instead

Comment: Although `@@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.`
`@@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session.` So your comment entirely depends on the architecture of your product. "Trusted" is unfair to say, but you should definitely appropriate your code with your dataflow.

Comment: I don't disagree, this isn't wrong, but I was just trying to say that there are newer and safer ways to get the identity.