# How can I assign inserted output value to a variable in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Output Clause into a scalar variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558582/sql-server-output-clause-into-a-scalar-variable)

```
DECLARE @id int
INSERT INTO MyTable(name)
OUTPUT @id = Inserted.id
VALUES('XYZ')
```

I am trying like above. How is it possible?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use table variable to get id

```
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @table table (id int);
INSERT INTO MyTable(name)
OUTPUT inserted.id into @table
VALUES('XYZ');

SELECT @id = id from @table;
```

Comment: Thanks sir, Is it not possible directly assign to int variable?

Comment: No, you cannot use local variable. If you use above code you can access data and set value from table to a variable

Comment: @RakeshHolkar - The INSERT syntax allows you to insert multiple records, so the OUTPUT syntax must be able to also deal with multiple records. As such, even if you only insert one record, OUTPUT returns a set of data to you. Even though that set is a single row with just one field, it's a set, and not an integer.

Comment: @MatBailie: That makes sense, but it conflicts with the fact that it's perfectly valid to make variable assignments in 'select' clauses that return multiple rows.  For example: `declare @id bigint = 0; select @id = ID from TableWithManyIDs; print @id;` The @id variable will take on the last row's ID value and it will be printed.  For a single insert statement, therefore, it makes sense that the output clause, which basically functions as a select statement should support that same syntax such as `output @id = inserted.ID`.  Instead, it fails with a syntax error around the '='.

Comment: @Triynko - That syntax assigns every row's `id` to `@id`, with (as you say) only the last assignment being visible at the end.  The problem being that `the last row` is not necessarily the last row inserted.  Clustered Indexes, fragmentation and a whole host of other factors means that without an ***explicit*** `ORDER BY`, you don't actually know which row will be last, and so have it's `id` in `@id`.  Not to mention that on large tables it's highly inefficient.  As for variable assignment within an OUTPUT, are you sure it's not expecting a TABLE variable there?

Comment: Lets be clear here, we're only interested in assigning a single value, so it will always be the last value inserted, because it's the only value inserted. The justification that insert can't do what select does because "it returns a set" is bull, because "select" also returns a set and yet it allows assignment to a variable.  The output clause basically makes it a select statement.  So why does output, unlike select, require the expensive operation of declare a whole table? It's not good when the procedure is called rapidly; those table variable creations start to add up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using "Scope_identity" function. The following blog has further explanation:

- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: What if one doesn't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`? Especially when the `id` is a form of a `GUID`...