# SQL Server: Use output parameter values in the same procedure also

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEmployee]
    (
        @employeeId int OUTPUT,
        @firstName varchar(50),
        @lastName varchar(50),
        @password varchar(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employees(FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES(@firstName, @lastName)

    INSERT INTO Logins(Password, EmployeeId)
    VALUES(@password, @employeeId)

    SELECT @@Identity
END
GO
```

Let,

```
 @employeeId = EmployeeId
```

generated during insert in `Employees`

After that, I was trying to insert the `@employeeId` into the `Logins` table.

Also, the `@employeeId` is used as `OUTPUT` parameter.

How should I do it?

May be we can use `INSERTED.EmployeeId`, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your EmployeeId column is an IDENTITY column, you should use the OUTPUT clause to fetch the value (you output it into a table variable):

```
DECLARE @empId TABLE (empId int)

INSERT INTO Employees
(
    FirstName, LastName
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.EmployeeId INTO @empId
VALUES
(
    @firstName,
    @lastName
)
```

Then to get the value from the table variable into a scalar variable, do:

```
SET @employeeId = (SELECT TOP 1 empId FROM @empId)
```

Comment: +1 This should work fine.  Your second query can be abbreviated as `select @employeeId = empId from @empId`

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEmployee] (
    @firstName VARCHAR(50)
    , @lastName VARCHAR(50)
    , @password VARCHAR(100)
    , @employeeId INT OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employees (
        FirstName
        , LastName
        )
    VALUES (
        @firstName
        , @lastName
        )

    SELECT @employeeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Logins (
        Password
        , EmployeeId
        )
    VALUES (
        @password
        , @employeeId
        )

END
GO

EXEC [dbo].[AddEmployee] @firstname = 'test'
    , @lastname = 'tester'
    , @password = '321321'
    , @employeeId = ''
```

Comment: Why does your stored procedure end with `select @@identity` ?

Comment: @Andomar oh that was copy pasted from OP, removed it as it actually changes the behavior. thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Now your answer looks fine, +1

Comment: +1 This answer is definitely better than the Accepted Answer. The only improvement should be to update the example `EXEC` at the end to show `DECLARE @EmpID INT;` and then the last line of the proc call should be: `, @employeeId = @EmpID OUTPUT;`.

Answer (score 2):

The `@@Identity` value is the last identity inserted in the current session regardless of scope.  Hence, it could be the identity of a row inserted by a trigger.  It's always better to use `scope_identity()` instead.  For more details, [see MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558582/sql-server-output-clause-into-a-scalar-variable).

You can assign an output parameter like:

```
set @employeeId = scope_identity()
```