# SQL Output statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, output

Please help me editing following SQL Server stored procedure to get the `ID` of last inserted row using an `OUTPUT` statement so that retrieve it throw C# code behind like

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(insertUser.ExecuteScalar());
```

Stored procedure code:

```
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ID INT 

    INSERT INTO dbo.Registration_Table (StudentName, Email, CourseCode, CourseTitle) 
    VALUES (@StudentName, @Email, @CourseCode, @CourseTitle)  

    SELECT 2
END
GO
```

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using SQL and .Net ,please edit my code

Comment: **SQL** is the query language - but it's just by **most** RDBMS systems - and we really need to know which **CONCRETE** RDBMS system you're using - Oracle? SQL Server? DB2? MySQL? PostgresQL? **SQL** isn't clear enough ...

Comment: i am using MS SQL. What i need is to get the ID of row inserted back by stored procedure

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558582/sql-server-output-clause-into-a-scalar-variable

Answer (score 1):

you should add a 'Transact-SQL' tag to this post.

The answer is

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

although for completeness, i should also mention that you can use the output clause in the insert statement, but that would imo only be useful if you insert more than one row.

Comment: i am using MS SQL. What i need is to get the ID of row inserted back by stored procedure.  Scope identity work for me but i want to get the result by OUTPUT

Comment: @Mansoor: but if this approach with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` works - why do you insist on using `OUTPUT` ??

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() may give error as i read. i need the ID of particular row inserted by that stored procedure

Comment: If your insert statement inserts more than one record, the optimizer may execute it in parallel, in which case SCOPE_IDENTITY may not return the exact last record id. In your statement, only one record is inserted, and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last id.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i made it. if anyone want id of last inserted column through stored procedure using OUTPUT clause just use following code. SCOPE_IDENTITY() may lead to error during parallel insertion by multiple users

```
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID INT);

    INSERT INTO dbo.Registration_Table(StudentName,Email,CourseCode,CourseTitle)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @IDs(ID) 
    VALUES (@StudentName, @Email, @CourseCode, @CourseTitle)  

   SELECT ID FROM @IDs;
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you reference where you read that SCOPE_IDENTITY may cause an error with multiple users? I've never had any problem.

Comment: Nick ,  please folow this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2019779/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identit