# How to pass the result id of a row into the next sql request?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say that  i have two relational tables : table A and table B.

table B have a foreign key of table A , so in order to insert a row in B we need first to insert a row in A.
so i have inserted the first row in A :

insert into A (c1,c2) values(v1,v2)

What i want is to get the id of the inserted row to use it as a foreign key when i insert into the table b . how to do that ?

while searching for a solution i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558582/sql-server-output-clause-into-a-scalar-variable) , that i need to declare a new table:

```
declare @KEY table(KEY int)

Insert into A (c1,c2)
Output inserted.Id into @kEY
values(v1,v2)
```

but when i tried to use it :

```
 Insert into B (C1,C2) values(@KEY,v2)
```

I get an error telling the @KEY is not declared !

so any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table variable is not the same thing as a scalar variable. You can't use the `values` clause like this with a table variable - you need to select from it:

```
declare @KEY table(KEY int)

Insert into A (c1,c2)
Output inserted.Id into @kEY
values(v1,v2)

Insert into B (C1) 
Select [Key]
From @Key;
```

Comment: ok how to do that into my values clause ? i can't do this values(select [key] from@key), should i create a select before an put it into a local variable ?

Comment: You don't do that into your values clause, the `select` is instead of the `values` clause. If you need extra data you can do `select [Key], 'HardCodedString', @Variable FROM @Key`

Comment: what if i have other columnes , how they get their values, i think the solution is to get the select out ,pass the result in a variable and then insert it in values

Comment: In an insert statement, you can output anything from the `inserted` pseudo table to you table variable (providing it has the relevant columns)